# When using NSURLConnection in main(), why the connection can not finished?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm testing the [HTTPFileUploadSample](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample) now. Because I want to use it to create a type of command tool line program, so i call the method in the main() function, like this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Uploader *upl = [Uploader alloc]; 
        [upl initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/uploader.php"]
                filePath:@"/test.txt"
                delegate:upl
            doneSelector:@selector(onUploadDone)
           errorSelector:@selector(onUploadError)];
           //[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];   
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I found it can create the connection and post request normally, but it can not finish the connection, because it do not call those delegate methods(**connection:didReceiveResponse:** or **connection:didReceiveData:** or **connectionDidFinishLoading:**) at all. 
So I call the method **[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]** to run loop (as the comment in codes), then everything is ok. I do not know why. Can anybody give me some explanation? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runloop is a big event handler infinite loop (well, infinite until it's stopped). It watches various sources and when they generate events it dispatches those events to listeners. This is a very effective way to manage asynchronous operations on a single thread.

`NSURLConnection` (and many other things in Cocoa) rely on the runloop for their processing. If nothing runs the runloop, then the events aren't processed.

Comment: Thanks! I wanna to know if there is any other ways to substitute for using runloop?

Comment: For commandline apps, you can use `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, which is synchronous (blocking until done), and so should not require a runloop.